# What is the difference between following two string cases

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am trying to assign the value to string and then access it, but for the 1st case i didnt get output as wanted....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
      
      string abc;

      abc[0] = 'm';

      cout << "str1 : " << abc    << endl;
      cout << "str1 : " << abc[0] << endl;

      //-----------------------------------

      string xyz;

      xyz = "village";

      cout << "str2 : " << xyz    << endl;
      cout << "str2 : " << xyz[0] << endl;

      return 0;
}
```

**Output Should Be :**

> str1 : m
> str1 : m
> str2 : village
> str2 : v

**But Actually It Is :**

> str1 :
> str1 : m
> str2 : village
> str2 : v

Comment: If you want use `std::string` with the subscript (`operator[]`) you have to ensure beforehand that the string has sufficient length (regardless whether you intend to read or write). [std::string::resize()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) is one way to achieve this. If you want to cut off the rest of a string then you can use `erase()` or `resize()`. Please, note that the `std::string` manages its storage internally. Whenever something is inserted or removed, the storage is adjusted when necessary but overwriting individual characters doesn't change the length.

Comment: Asking "What's the difference" goes out the window when you use bogus code.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are replacing the `null`-terminator (which each string has at end, to mark end), with `m`, and probably causing a lot of random output, if not `SIGSEG` crash and/or undefined behavior.

### Solutions

#### Array style

```
std::string myVariable;

// ...

myVariable.resize(3, '\x0');
myVariable[0] = 'm';
myVariable[1] = 'a';
myVariable[2] = 'x';
// And index 3 is already null-terminator (no need to set manually to zero).
```

#### What you should do instead

If speed is not a concern, and you just want stability and ease of use, try something like:

```
abc += 'm';
```

OR

```
abc.append(1, 'm');
```

Comment: What would be solution for that?

Comment: if i want to assign and access in this way only......

Comment: @AdityaVaste If you want to be able to set and/or use `std::string` like an array, then see [how to reserve memory](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) (and never use an index higher then what you reserve in advance).

Answer (score 0):

There is a **mistake** in your program as described below.

**Mistake**

```
string abc; //this creates a **0 sized** default constructed string object
abc[0] = 'm';// incorrect because you're trying to assign to the 0th index of the string object abc but note that there is no 0th index because the string has 0 size.
```

Note that the statement

```
abc[0] = 'm';
```

is incorrect because at the moment the string object `abc` has 0 size and you're trying to access the 1st element(which have 0th index). But wait, how can you access the 1st element(or 0th index) of a string that doesn't have any element because it is of size 0.

**Solution 1**

Instead of assigning to the 0th index you can append to the string `abc` using

```
abc += 'm';
```

**Solution 2**

You can also create a `std::string` with a particular size(length) and element as follows:

```
std::string abc(1, 'm'); //now abc has size(length) of 1 and has the element(0th element) as "m".
```

with this you don't need to use the assignment you're doing. That is now you **don't need** `abc[0] = 'm';`